# Why is webdavfs_agent consuming 100% of CPU?

Tags: network, performance, webdav

I'm getting very high CPU usage whenever I access a WebDAV shared drive (in Mac OS Big Sur v11.1, running on a 2019 MacBookPro 16").

My employer uses a WebDAV server for shared files, and I access this using "Connect To Server..." in the Finder. I find that if I mount this shared drive, and leave it mounted for more than a couple of minutes, CPU usage abruptly goes up to 100% and stays there, with fans going at high speed and the machine getting noticeably warm. The problem is immediately solved if I unmount the network share, but that stops me doing my job!

Looking in "top" it seems that webdavfs_agent is taking up 98% of one core, and logd is using 12% of another. I'm guessing logd is somehow accessing lots of files on the shared drive, but I can't work out how to stop it doing so. I wondered if it was the Spotlight indexing service, but disabling that with "mdutil -a -i off" doesn't seem to make a difference. I also didn't find anything relevant in the Apple System Log messages (so whatever logd is doing, it's not actually writing any logs that I can see).

How can I stop this happening?